# SELECT id WHERE COUNT(*) > X ? - How to get records from any user that has more than X records in table?

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

Obviously the query in the title does not work, but it might illustrate in a naive way, what I would like to do. I have a table that contains some users identified by an id column. This id is NOT unique within the database. It marks a user that may have multiple records in my table.

How can I show the whole record of all users (identified by id) that have more than 10 records in my table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **having** instead of **where**:

```
SELECT id
  FROM (
        SELECT id, COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM somewhere 
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING cnt > 1
   ) temp_table
```

Comment: This one here really fast and has exactly the same result as my query. Though it's more elegant of course ;) . Why is this little difference in HAVING causing so much difference compared to Ishtar's approach?

Comment: This is the exact same as my approach except mine doesn't have the extra SELECT statement surrounding it. Why do you need the extra SELECT?

Comment: I don't need it, it just allows you to sort by non-aggregate columns with outermost select.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM user GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 10)
```

Comment: I can't really tell why, but this really long compared to mine.

Comment: @ran2 - long? What do you mean? Slow??

Comment: dammit. I don't know what I was thinking when in wrote that. Probably I wanted to write it takes longer than mine. Good guess, though ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
```

Comment: Remove COUNT(*) from the beginning if you just want the id's, but I put it in there to show the total number for each id in the table.

Answer (score 0):

here is how:

```
 CREATE TABLE mytable_clean AS
 SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN(
 SELECT id FROM
 (SELECT id,COUNT(*) AS appearance 
 FROM mytable
 GROUP BY id) AS id_count
 WHERE id_count.appearance > 9 )
```

It does work. It's not to slow, but looks a little clumsy to me. Better solutions welcome :)